# Is the reason why lipid-soluble molecules can pass through membrane because

Tags: cell-membrane

I have been studying about cell membranes and how water molecules are able to pass through it. (https://www.wiley.com/college/boyer/0470003790/animations/membrane_transport/membrane_transport.htm)

It is clear that the water molecules can squeeze through openings in the bilayer. My questions are:

1) Do small, non-polar molecules also enter through these gaps?

2) It states that the whole structure moves when vibrating. Does that mean the hydrophobic tails also move? If so, how do the non-polar molecules dissolve?

3) The top of the membrane is hydrophilic. How do non-polar molecules get past these hydrophilic heads into the hydrophobic interior core where they can be dissolved?

Thanks a lot!